# appending results from two sql queries with same fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

i have two sql queries which give resultset with same attributes... i want to combine these two result sets...
my first query gives

```
order_id     frequency
-------------------------
1             5
3             7
10            2
12            3
```

and second query gives

```
order_id     frequency
-------------------------
1             3
10            2
12            8
```

### what i finally want in result is

```
order_id     frequency
-------------------------
1             5
3             7
10            2
12            3
1             3
10            2
12            8
```

here union will not work as if there is are two same tuples such as pair
    10            2
it should appear twice.

### please suggest some mysql query;

Comment: Have you read up on `UNION ALL` ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with UNION ALL?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
UNION ALL
```

to avoid removing dups.

Answer (score 0):

You need **[Union All](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)**

*`Union` must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists*

```
Select order_id, frequency from Table_A
Union All
Select order_id, frequency from Table_B
```